# How to handle uncaught error in simple-peer library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I'm currently using feross' simple-peer library and I sometimes get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Ice connection failed.
at r._onIceStateChange 
at RTCPeerConnection.t._pc.oniceconnectionstatechange
```

This error comes straight from the library and I'm not sure how to catch it without editing it. Is there any way to implement something akin to try > catch within my script instead of the library?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You may use a global uncaught error or you can wrap your code with a try catch block

Comment: @JanithKasun the relevant code is several blocks of simple-peer events and it is quite long.
The actual error stems from the library (the source is simple-peer.js line 1) and webRTC and it is unrelated to my code. It happens when the two peers fail the connection because of a firewall or a symmetric NAT but the library doesn't handle the scenario. I'm supposed to handle it without altering the library itself.

Your idea of using a global handler is good though.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a global error handler for the process using,

```
process
    .on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
        // HANDLE ERROR HERE
    })
    .on('uncaughtException', err => {
        // HANDLE ERROR HERE
    });
```